# how to add an attachment to an email in Symfony?

Tags: php, email, symfony1, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I want to add an attachment to an email. I am using sfmailer class.

Here I have given my code below:

```
$mail_body = '<p>custom html mail content</p>';
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Message title')
  ->setFrom(array('sender'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver'))
  ->setBody($mail_body, 'text/html', 'utf-8');

try {
  $this->getMailer()->send($message);
}
catch(Exception $e) {

}
```

Comment: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files

Answer (score 31):

You have several options to attach a document to an email using swift mailer.

From [the symfony doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/11-Emails#chapter_11_sub_the_powerful_way):

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setFrom('from@example.com')
  ->setTo('to@example.com')
  ->setSubject('Subject')
  ->setBody('Body')
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('/path/to/a/file.zip'))
;

$this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

And many others possibility from [the swift mailer doc](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files).

Answer (score 3):

Also you can attach a file by resource.

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setFrom('from@example.com')
  ->setTo('to@example.com')
  ->setSubject('Subject')
  ->setBody('Body')
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($content, 'invoice.pdf','application/pdf'));
```